# Git Log difference between 2 releases

Tags: git, branch, git-log

Running on Windows I have difficulty trying to get the following working:

This delivers nothing:

```
git log --oneline -- 'release/1.4.34'...'release/1.4.35'
```

This delivers an error "fatal: ambiguous argument ''release/1.4.33'...'release/1.4.34'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] -- [...]'"

```
git log --oneline 'release/1.4.33'...'release/1.4.34'
```

This delivers: fatal: bad revision ''release/1.4.33'...'release/1.4.34''

```
git log --oneline 'release/1.4.33'...'release/1.4.34' --
```

Without quotes delivers: fatal: ambiguous argument 'release/1.4.33...release/1.4.34': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'

```
git log --oneline release/1.4.33...release/1.4.34
```

Basically I want all commits between 2 releases.

**UPDATE**

Found it! the Ambiguity was ofcourse between origin and the local... working:

```
git log --oneline origin/release/1.4.33...origin/release/1.4.34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes :

```
git log --oneline release/1.4.33...release/1.4.34
```

As a sidenote, `--` is used to tell git "every argument which follows is to be taken as path", you don't need it for what you're trying to achieve.

Also, since `1.4.34` is obviously posterior to `1.4.33`, you wouldn't have to use symetrical difference (`A...B`) but probably rather a simple range (`A..B`)